# Merging 2 dataframes but so rows are stacked in between eachother

Tags: r, merge, rows

This might be a really simple problem but I could not find the solution to it. I am using Rstudio. I have 2 dataframes with many rows. Lets say I have

RowA1

RowA2

RowA3

Then another table with rows

RowB1

RowB2

RowB3

They have the same number of columns as well. 
I want a new table to have rows layered like this:

RowA1

RowB1

RowA2

RowB2

RowA3

RowB3

and so on...

I don't have any reproducible work because the tables I am using are created from filters and various datasets. Any help is great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `rbind` the datasets and then order the rows

```
out <- rbind(df1, df2)[order(c(seq_len(nrow(df1)), seq_len(nrow(df2)))),]
```

---

If the datasets have only a single column and have the same number of rows

```
data.frame(col1 = c(rbind(df1[[1]], df2[[2]])))
```